# Append data in each <td> with AJAX/JQUERY to a table generated from JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I have a database full of descriptions and id numbers, and the table is populated with them as follows:

**index.jsp**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Id:</td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${employee}" var="employee">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="$employee.description"></c:out></td>
            <td class="id-value" id="id"><c:out value="$employee.id"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</table>
```

That works fine, all the values show up in the table.  What I also have is a service that will take the ID as a parameter and return the first name and last name of the particular employee - and I want to append that to the table for each record so they show up when the page loads - removing the need to store more values in the database.  Here is my current code:

**function.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(request, response) {
    var id = $('#id').text();
    var serviceUrl = 'http/service/example';

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: serviceUrl + id,
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
    $.map(JSON.parse(data), function(item) {
        $('td.id-value').append(' ' + item.FNAME + ' ' + item.LNAME);
   });
 }
});
});
```

What happens is that when the page loads the  id-column is full of all the correct id numbers, but they all have the same first name and last name appended over and over (the first / last name of the first id).

How can I make it so the call is made for each value in that column?

**json response**

```
 {FNAME: "FIRSTNAME", LNAME: "LASTNAME"}
```

Comment: All your `<td>` elements with ids have the same value for `id` attribute. That might be the root cause.

Comment: @Ivan changing the name of the <td> id did not change anything.

Comment: What did you change it to? @Ivan's point was all of your rows had the same id, regardless of what that is.

Comment: @Drewness

I changed the <td> id to #test-id, but I am only declaring an id on the single row I expect to have the values from the service call appended to.

The issue is the service is only being called once and repeating the value for the first id it finds, instead of making the call for each id in each row.  I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to get list of elements like this

```
$("td[id='id']").each(function(e) {
  var elem = $(this)
  var id = elem.text();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: serviceUrl + id,
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      $.map(JSON.parse(data), function(item) {
      elem.append(' ' + item.FNAME + ' ' + item.LNAME);
  });
})
```

Comment: awesome!  That worked great.

I am now getting an 'elem.append is not a function' error in my browser console.  Any workaround for that?

Comment: @Evan, strange, I've checked with jQuery 3.3.1 and it works. You could set a  breakpoint on that line and check what methods are available for `elem`

Comment: @Evan, you could try to use `elem.text(elem.text() + ' ' + item.FNAME + ' ' + item.LNAME);` but you'd better use debugger to check what's wrong.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see if the error goes away, going to accept this answer as it did solve my problem.

Thanks!